# Train N networks in parallel on CPU using Tensorflow Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, parallel-processing

I would like to train multiple networks in parallel on the CPU to save time. Here is an example of two networks that I would like to train in a parallel fashion instead of sequentially. Please note that the callbacks for each model differ.

```
import tensorflow as tf

def learning_rate_scheduler_1(epoch, lr):
    lr = tf.exp(-float(epoch)) * lr
    return lr

def learning_rate_scheduler_2(epoch, lr):
    lr =  lr / (epoch + 1.0)
    return lr

callback_1 = tf.keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler(learning_rate_scheduler_1)
callback_2 = tf.keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler(learning_rate_scheduler_2)


model_1 = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
])

model_2 = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
])

model_1.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.001),
                loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                metrics=['accuracy'])

model_2.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.001),
                loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                metrics=['accuracy'])

model_1.summary()
model_2.summary()

data = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = data.load_data()

model_1.fit(x=x_train, y=y_train, epochs=2, callbacks=[callback_1])
model_2.fit(x=x_train, y=y_train, epochs=2, callbacks=[callback_2])
```

Comment: have you tried running them on different processes?

Comment: @MZ No, I'm not familiar with running code on different processes. How difficult would that be? I hoped that Keras provides some tools I'm currently not aware of.

Comment: it's not too bad. you would be able to do it with `threading` really easily too - just start a thread and point one of the fit methods to it.

Comment: @MZ Ok, I currently try do parallelize the code above using Python Multiprocessing. Given the example above, should I use the Process or Pool class for parallelization?